# send request to XSD by web service using PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, xsd

I am writing PHP code for consuming a web service. The link which I am sending my request is this: http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?Wsdl

This is whats inside the link:

```html
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="Gateway" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CPGatewayWebServices"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IGatewayServices_ChargeSubscriberRequest_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ChargeSubscriberRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IGatewayServices_ChargeSubscriberRequest_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ChargeSubscriberRequestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IGatewayServices">
<wsdl:operation name="ChargeSubscriberRequest">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IGatewayServices/ChargeSubscriberRequest" message="tns:IGatewayServices_ChargeSubscriberRequest_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IGatewayServices/ChargeSubscriberRequestResponse" message="tns:IGatewayServices_ChargeSubscriberRequest_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGatewayServices" type="tns:IGatewayServices">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ChargeSubscriberRequest">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IGatewayServices/ChargeSubscriberRequest" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Gateway">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IGatewayServices" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IGatewayServices">
<soap:address location="http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

as you see I have a xsd element in my xml which is imported:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
```

My purpose is to send some request to the link I mentioned, then the xml code should send my request automatically to this xsd tag, and then the xsd which contains another xml file (in `http://79.175.138.93/Gateway.svc?xsd=xsd0`) should give me back some information.

That's my problem! The PHP code can't recognize the xsd tag and nothing is giving back as a result, but when I use "SoapUI" it works.

What should I do? How can I send my info to the xml inside the imported xsd by PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The host does not seem to be reachable, can you provide all the schema?

If you want, you can try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) from your environment (which whould be able to reach the host), it will ease the Web Service consumption.